# дождаться конечной обработки сервера

Tags: python

есть [cсылка](https://savesubs.com/process?url=https://youtu.be/E5yFcdPAGv0) . Ей надо время прогрузится, чтоб потом из кнопки достать ссылку на загрузку файла. Вопрос можно ли всё это провернуть без selenium, но если без selenium никак, тогда чтоб не открывался сам браузер.

P.S. в скрытом браузере загрузка файла у меня не получилась

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опция --headless чтоб не открывать окно браузера.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# chrome_options.headless = True # also works
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
start_url = "https://duckgo.com"
driver.get(start_url)
print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
# b'<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www....
driver.quit()
```

а без селениум попробуй API этого сайта

```
curl 'https://savesubs.com/action/extract' \
  -H 'authority: savesubs.com' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'cookie: __cf_bm=vsauMS7ZZtK089UppcJyOXxEv9q6CXRmYj7vttr.eEw-1658746708-0-AfuV3lvg4ZLd2jrOz2FikOtuQJGh4znA3oLvYGfJlRCjZv5dtefeB3dSXEKILIif43UOOBdYTaXaKtc8/xMkAZ+i3hzp0sSQxTPB0Do6RWaS/LReDKbOCMKhbA7g0y6khA==' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: https://savesubs.com' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'referer: https://savesubs.com/process?url=https://youtu.be/E5yFcdPAGv0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-auth-token: o5Orm9fWxtVilqLOk5ZoycObm2VjZZaXxZPJxGtsZJGTrpyxlYSNf6adopnMu7u1g4WFusCuc7mn' \
  -H 'x-requested-domain: savesubs.com' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: xmlhttprequest' \
  --data-raw '{"data":{"url":"https://youtu.be/E5yFcdPAGv0"}}' \
  --compressed
```

x-auth-token попробуй достать из безголового селениума

Comment: @Senshi для перевода с curl на пайтон используйте https://curlconverter.com/